# What's the best ORM framework for GWT applications?

Tags: gwt, orm

I am developing my graduate project, using GWT.

I use TOMCAT as the applciation server and MySQL as the database.

I want to persist all data existing in the client to the database using an ORM.

There are various ORM solutions for GWT such as Hibernate, JPA, JDO, TopLink, etc.

Do you have any suggestions?

Regards.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) for sure

Comment: Why? Could you care to elaborate at least a bare minimum? Last I checked, Hibernate had issues with GWT, and other answers seem to indicate this has not changed.

Comment: @Hugo, before downvote, offer at least something different.

Comment: I don't have one, that's why I was reading this question. Hibernate is know to **not work** with GWT. I downvoted because that's what corresponded in this scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Not all of hibernate features are compatible with GWT, however it does not men that the answer is incorrect.

Comment: I found this answer non-useful, so I clicked the button that says "This answer is not useful". There's also no description or **anything** on your answer, just a mere link (one word too). At least bother elaborating *why* you consider this the best ORM to work with GWT. The answer is not correct, because it does not even abide to SO's guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate is not easy to integrate with GWT because of following reasons

- Lazy properties issue : when trying to send a partially loaded Hibernate POJO to the client-side of GWT (Javascript), the GWT compiler throws a Serialization exception because it the CGLIB generated proxy does not belong to the JRE emulation.
- Type issue : Hibernate replaces some basic Java types with various subclassed implementation (such as java.sql.Timestamp instead of java.util.Date or PersistentList for List collections). Javascript serialization of these classes will fail, since they do not belong to the JRE emulation supported by GWT 1.4 (note : the Java SQL dates are now supported by GWT 1.5)

REF
http://www.rbgrn.net/content/32-using-hibernate-with-google-web-toolkit-gwt